# Writing from one form to another

Tags: javascript, text, webforms, input

I have two forms.

Form A has three text input; A1, A2, A3.  Form B has one text input, B1.

Whenever you type in any of the inputs on Form A, Form B should get updated, right away, with all three inputs from Form A.  If one of the Form A inputs is empty, a 0 should replace it in B1.

For example, if I'm typing "test" in A1 and leave A2 and A3 empty, B1 should reflect: test+0+0.  If I'm typing "test" in A1 and "help" in A2, and leave A3 empty, then B1 should reflect: test+help+0

Can anyone assist with this?  I have very limited experience with Javascript so I'm not even sure how to search for such aspects of this feature.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Add a method to the onChange event of each input on the A form such as: onChange=populateBField();

```
Function populateBField(){
 document.formB.B1.value = getFieldContents("A1") + "+" + getFieldContents("A2") 
 + "+" + getFieldContents("A3");
}

function getFieldContents(fieldName){
   var fieldValue = document.formA.fieldName.value;
   // if no value is entered, set to 0
   if (fieldValue.length < 1){
       fieldValue = 0;
   }
   return fieldValue;
}
```

Please point out any errors/improvements as I'm a relative JS newbie myself :)

Answer (score 1):

A start, using [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org)

```
function build_b() {
    var str = "";
    str += "A1=" + ($F('A1') == ''? '0' : $F('A1'));
    str += "A2=" + ($F('A2') == ''? '0' : $F('A2'));
    str += "A2=" + ($F('A3') == ''? '0' : $F('A3'));
    $('B').value = str;
}
```

This assumes that the element ID's are A1, A2, A3 and B.
Bind this function to the 'onchange' event of A1, A2 and A3.